# Pycharm Smart Indent single new line

Tags: python, pycharm, settings

I'm trying to recreate my Pycharm settings on a new PC.

My issue is that while writing python code, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> within a bracket/brace pair gives me two new lines instead of one.

E.g.
Current behaviour

| Before <kbd>Enter</kbd> | After <kbd>Enter</kbd> |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Desired behaviour:

| Before <kbd>Enter</kbd> | After <kbd>Enter</kbd> |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Please give me the settings combination I need for the desired behaviour, I'm sure I've missed something obvious.

I'm on pycharm pro 2022.2

Comment: The one you want is actually the default behavior. Did you install any custom plugins?
Instead of manually recreating all the settings, you can do **File | Manag IDE Settings | Export Settings...** and then do the import on the new PC. Or try **IDE Settings Sync** in the same menu.

Comment: @SergeyK. Old PC is bricked unfortunately, otherwise I would have done that. I've not installed any plugins yet.

Comment: Does resetting to defaults help (use Restore Default Settings in the same menu)?

Comment: No. Doing that gives me the expected behaviour but then I lose all of my other config which takes a long time to recreate. Are you not able to give some more targeted suggestions?

Comment: I assumed that you were setting everything up from scratch since you didn't import the settings.
Try restoring default code style settings for Python in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Python**.